# php mkdir, folder name and structure

Tags: php

I need to make an new folder on my server, and this also works just fine using mkdir()

But can someone tell me how to make both folder name and structure using mkdir()??

Folder name will be = $_SESSION['username'];

and structure inside the new folder should be = /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/

Thanks for your time.

/thar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create file and folders recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650790/create-file-and-folders-recursively)

Comment: how should the folderstructure and the username play together?

Comment: Some people who probably knows the answer doubt to answer because of that 0%.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set third argument to `true` which allows you creation of nested directories:

```
mkdir($_SESSION['username'] . '/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/', 0777, true);
```